# Время new DateTime() в переменной

Tags: php, datetime

Почему после ->modify изменяются обе переменные?

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('d.m G:i')."\n";
$near = $date;
$near->modify('+1 day');
echo $near->format('d.m')."\n" ;
echo $date->format('d.m');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

А почему не должны?

У вас есть объект класса `DateTime` и две ссылки на него: `near` и `date`. Но объект по-прежнему один, потому изменения объекта, конечно, будут видны через обе ссылки на него.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

> A PHP reference is an alias, which allows two different variables to write to the same value. In PHP, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object.

Возможно, вам нужно [клонирование](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) или `DateTimeImmutable` класс, метод `modify` которого будет порождать новый объект.

Answer (score 1):

потому что это не копирование

```
$near = $date;
```

а присвоение

После данной строчки обе переменные ссылаются на один объект `DateTime`

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо.

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('d.m')."\n";
$near = clone $date;
$near->modify('+1 day');
echo $near->format('d.m')."\n" ;
echo $date->format('d.m');
?>
```